# Sum of 2 values in same lambda?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following LINQ query where I am having to seperate the `.Sum` into seperate calls, when I combine them I get an `NaN`. This doesn't work:

```
var rejectRate = (results.Sum(x => x.TraysRejectedDay / x.TraysProcessedDay)) * 100;
```

This does work:

```
var traysProcessed = results.Sum(x => x.TraysProcessedDay);
var rejectRate = (results.Sum(x => x.TraysRejectedDay / traysProcessed)) * 100;
```

Is this just a limitation of LINQ or am I doing something wrong? Both of the fields are the same data type (`double`)

Comment: Those are two different queries. The former divides every `TraysRejectedDay` through `TraysProcessedDay` and returns the sum. The latter divides every `TraysRejectedDay` through the sum of all `TraysProcessedDay` and returns the sum. Can `TraysProcessedDay` be zero?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are two different queries. The former divides every `TraysRejectedDay` through `TraysProcessedDay` and returns the sum. The latter divides every `TraysRejectedDay` through the sum of all `TraysProcessedDay` and returns the sum.

So if `TraysProcessedDay` for example can be 0 you'd divide through zero. Maybe you want to ignore them:

```
var rejectRate = (results
    .Where(x => x.TraysProcessedDay > 0)
    .Sum(x => x.TraysRejectedDay / x.TraysProcessedDay)) * 100;
```

Comment: Wouldn't that give a `DivideByZeroException` instead of `NaN`?

Comment: @Default: from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan.aspx): _"A method or operator returns NaN when the result of an operation is undefined. For example, the result of dividing zero by zero is NaN, ..."_